# pushView - set Longger time - iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have following code in my application.

[self.navigationController pushViewController:x animated:YES];

It will push a new view to the application.

I want to change the animation time for pushing.

What should I Do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the built-in UINavigationController Animation to accomplish this. It isn't customizable.

You will instead have to create your own animation, like with a CATransition. Then you can configure all of the attributes.

The only problem will be the navigation bar. You will have to handle that as well.

Also you will have to get the navigation hierarchy correct. You may have to be creative to get this right.